# Unable to create Actionbar for Lollipop

Tags: java, android, menu, android-actionbar

I'm having a small issue with my application in that I'm unable create an action-bar that would appear at the top of my application, I need this feature due to the majority of phones do not have a specific hardware button to bring up a menu but rely on touchscreen controls.

The code I currently have is shown below:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add(0,0,0, "Get Clients");
    menu.add(0,1,0, "Save Register");
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case 0:
            scan();
            break;
        case 1:
            postData();
            break;
    }
    return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case 0:
            scan();
            break;
        case 1:
            postData();
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Your code is related to a menu. Nothing here makes an ActionBar... I recommend you go through some tutorials about ActionBars and Toolbars.

Comment: Yeah.. It's quite sad that people buy phones with no hardware keys.

Comment: use `appcompact` library and check tutorials on the same

Comment: Thank you for the advice guys, i manage to get it to work